# Use a property from a parent liquid loop inside a liquid if statement

Tags: loops, for-loop, if-statement, jekyll, liquid

I am making a list of products sorted by category. There is a clear syntax error in the code below but it will illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

```html
{%- for category in site.categories %}
<h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
<ul>
    {%- for item in site.itens %}
    {%- if item.category == {{ category.title }} %}
    <li>{{ item.title }}</li>
    {%- endif %}
    {%- endfor %}
</ul>
{%- endfor %}
```

I am trying to figure out a way for my if statement to use the property value of the current loop. Any ideas on how I can make this work?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the curly brackets from the object inside your if statement and you are good to go.

```html
{%- for category in site.categories %}
<h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>
<ul>
    {%- for item in site.itens %}
    {%- if item.category == category.title %}
    <li>{{ item.title }}</li>
    {%- endif %}
    {%- endfor %}
</ul>
{%- endfor %}
```